# J2ME Bluetooth Multiplayer Game

Tags: java-me

I want to make multiplayer games with J2ME but I didn't find any game source codes. 
Where can I find sample game sources?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the following svn's:

http://code.google.com/p/oppositelock/
http://code.google.com/p/oware-midlet/

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your reply.  But I couldn't see any sample game codes in that svn's

Comment: Browse the trunk, here's an example - http://code.google.com/p/oppositelock/source/browse/jsr/trunk/src/numfum/j2me/jsr/Player.java or just do a svn checkout for the complete project

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at third-party J2ME gaming SDK sample codes as well. Check out the Tic-Tac-Toe sample from Skiller, it's a free, powerful and easy to use SDK. The advantage with such third-party SDKs is that a number of features are already implemented so you don't need to re-invent the wheel for anything and everything. I hope that helps.

Comment: Where to download?